# Tomcat restful web service database (JPA) with Netbeans does not work

Tags: rest, tomcat, jpa

I have been able to create Restful web services with JAX-RS for Tomcat. Using the Netbeans Restful web service from patterns wizard.
But I am not able to create Restfull web servicer from database with Netbeans wizard.
It miss some libraries. I add openJPA and Java EE web api 6 (over the added by the wizard). But it continues not working.
I added javaEE-TomEE 8.0 but did not work, either!

Does anybody know what have I to add to Tomcat to get JPA-Database Restful service working?

Moving to GlassFish is not an answer valid... I want to keep on Tomcat (adding the minimal)

Answer (score 0):

I have made some advances... 
With EclipseLink(JPA 2.0) I was able to connect MySQL in a desktop application... 
Then I switched to Apache OpenJPA and I was no able to get an EntityManagerFactory...
So it seems I choose a library incomplete...
I imagine, in Tomcat, I have to choose other library than OpenJPA.